# Does this sum of products of binomial coefficients have a simple closed form?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Let $c,m,k$ be positive integers. Is there a simple closed form for the following sum?
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{c-1} (-1)^i {c \choose i} {im \choose k} $$
*Mathematica* finds nothing, and *Maxima*'s implementation of Gosper's algorithm says that the summand isn't hypergeometric in $i$.

Comment: For the case $m=1$ you can get a simple closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{c}(-1)^i\binom{c}{i}\binom{im}{k}=[x^k]\sum_{i=0}^{c}(-1)^i\binom{c}{i}(1+x)^{mi}=[x^k]\left(1-(1+x)^m\right)^c.$$

Comment: Looks like a generating function is the cleanest solution I can hope for. Thanks!